# Server Side Include on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, server-side-includes

Amazon S3 has static website hosting, but does not support tags like:

```
<!--#include virtual="i/header.htm" -->
<!--#echo var="i/header.htm" -->
<!--#include file="i/header.htm" -->
```

Is there anyway to mimic this functionality without having some sort of JavaScript/AJAX content request for the header on every page on S3?

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascript to assemble the page in the client browser.  With jQuery:

```
$('#header').load('header.html');
```

This has a serious SEO drawback-- search engines like Google won't see the final page.

You could also embed content in the page as an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 provides flat file storage. Whatever logic you apply needs to be client-side.